# Ошибка установки библиотек

Tags: python

Когда я пытаюсь установить библиоткеку вылазит это
C:\Windows\system32>pip install mcpi
Не удается найти файл C:\Users\Валерий\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\pip.exe.

Comment: Интересно, откуда в `WindowsApps` файл `pip.exe`... Питон установлен? `pip.exe` будет в его папке

Answer (score 0):

По ходу у Вас не установился Pip. Самое просто переустановите python он должен установиться по умолчанию.

Если не поможет можно использовать скрипт [get-pip](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
И запустить его командой `python get-pip.py` из директории со скриптом

Третий вариант если он есть в папке с python до добавить его в PATH

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @Validoll обратите внимание на два последних пункта [Отметьте ответ как решение и Не благодарите автора ответа в комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).